# Create a new task in Jira using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Is there a way that I can create a new task in Jira by writing code in Jenkinsfile, I found the plugin to update the task but didn't got anything to create a new task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a plugin which actually integrates Jira with Jenkins when you are using jenkinsfile. [Jira-Pipeline plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/index.html)

Usage and documentation is described in the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use curl to create an issue via the [JIRA REST api](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue).

Without knowing what you've tried and what errors you've received (if any), it's kind of difficult to be more specific.